# MySQL UNION ALL vs muliple SELECT performance on large databses

Tags: mysql, performance, performance-testing

I have 3 large databases, and I need to run the same query on all 3 of them. The query looks like this:

```
SELECT table1.a, table1.b, table2.a, table2.c 
FROM databse_A.table1 
INNER JOIN databse_A.table2 ON table1.a = table2.a
```

I decided to use UNION ALL to combine results from multiple databases so the query in the end looked like this:

```
SELECT table1.a, table1.b, table2.a, table2.c 
FROM databse_A.table1 
INNER JOIN databse_A.table2 ON table1.a = table2.a 
UNION ALL 
SELECT table1.a, table1.b, table2.a, table2.c 
FROM databse_B.table1 
INNER JOIN databse_B.table2 ON table1.a = table2.a 
UNION ALL 
SELECT table1.a, table1.b, table2.a, table2.c 
FROM databse_C.table1 
INNER JOIN databse_C.table2 ON table1.a = table2.a
```

The above query took 0.0068 to execute and returned around 3000 rows. Then I decided to test the same without `UNION ALL`. I cleared the database cache and run every `SELECT` as a separate query (every query returned around 1000 rows) and in the end that 3 queries took 0.0023 (in sum) to execute.

When the database cached the queries times changed from 0.0068 to 0.0055 and from 0.0023 to 0.0013.

So my question is why is there almost 3x difference between queries that do the same thing in the end. Do returned number of rows have anything to do with this?

If yes, is it better to have multiple queries that return a smaller number of rows than one big query that returns a large number of rows?

Comment: Could be that there is some overhead in integrating the sets. Then again, the overhead is minimal, you're talking about 4 milliseconds here. Depending on your server setup and the way you use the results, you may lose more than that just in roundtrip times and processing overhead.

Comment: Btw, you do know that it's allowed to have line breaks and whitespace in queries, right? ;)

Comment: Why not have one database instead of three?

Comment: @GolezTrol Yes I know, these were copied from PHP code.

Comment: @Strawberry because that's the optimal data structure we decided to use.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

First of all, under 10ms is so small in MySQL queries that it is hardly worth debating or comparing.

It used to be that all `UNIONs` would create a temp table and collect the data into it from each `SELECT`.  Then it delivers the rows from the temp table to the client.  That says that the `UNION` might be slower.

What version do you have?  The latest versions of MySQL have an optimization that would help *your* test case (but not all cases of `UNION` -- it will dispense with the temp table, and deliver rows from one `SELECT` at a time directly to the client.

There is a non-trivial overhead for each separate SQL you send to the server.  The `UNION` is 1 SQL; the 3 separate `SELECTs` is 3.  That says that the `UNION` might be faster, especially for newer versions.

Also, because of the overheads mentioned above, 1000 rows (small) may not be representative of what will happen with 1000000 rows (medium) or 1 billion (huge).  (I don't know what you consider "large", but 1000 is definitely not "large".)

Bear in mind, also, that a significant part of the 1.3ms is the time it takes to send the data back to the client.